# Switching from dataflow sdk to beam sdk causing exceptions in URN lookup

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We changed from the dataflow sdk (2.5.0) to apache beam sdk (2.12.0) with no changes in the code.

We get the following error message

`Expected DoFn to be FunctionSpec with URN urn:beam:dofn:javasdk:0.1, but URN was`

Is there any other setting that has to be done?

It seems to be failing for this line

`pipeline.apply(<some code here>).watchForNewFiles(10, Watch.Growth.never()))`

Comment: Would you please add some more detail, and the stack trace?

Comment: Perhaps also your pom file?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the apache beam sdk to 2.10.0 worked for this one in the GCP environment.